# What is the right exception to throw in a supposed-to-be-unreachable place?

Tags: .net, exception

For example,

```
switch (number)
{
    case 1: return DoOne();
    case 2: return DoTwo();
    case 3: return DoThree();
    case 4: return DoFour();

    default:
        throw new ???Exception("Unexpected number encountered.");
}
```

For the sake of this question, please assume:

- `number` is a private field in a class
- It is a class invariant that `number` should always be between 1 and 4; everything else indicates a bug in this class. In other words, if the exception triggers, it is *never* the caller’s fault but *always* the class’s author’s.

What is the correct exception to throw in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited**

There is no good default CLR exception that fits this situation. You should roll your own. I'd derive directly from exception, as you probably don't want this error to get mixed up with other types of errors.

There are situations where a program can recover from this seemingly unrecoverable situation: If you can be sure that the problem in this class can not spread to elsewhere. This is for instance when you use this class as part of a function that has no side effects. This may seem a contrived example, but it isn't when you purposely write or package code such that it is free from side effects.

I don't think you should do something drastic like exiting the program (as suggested in another now deleted answer). As a class author that is not your responsibility.

As an author of the sofware using this class, I would like to get the opportunity to tell the user that something bad happend, try to save backups, log information, write stuff to databases.... you get the picture.

Comment: Throwing `Exception` itself is a **DON’T** in the [Framework Design Guidelines](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Framework-Design-Guidelines-Conventions-Libraries/dp/0321246756). Otherwise, this answer makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Timwi: In retrospect, I agree. It does make you wonder why they didn't make Exception an abstract class in the first place. I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

In Java I would use an [AssertionError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html).

Answer (score 2):

Since the error is due to faulty state, use `InvalidOperationException`. If `number` had been an argument to the method being called, I would have thrown an `ArgumentException`.

Comment: Hmmm... This still implicitly puts the blame on the guy that initiated the 'Invalid Operation'.

Comment: @jdv: The docs indicate a close enough match for me... I guess it depends on how you interpret the wording.

Comment: I don’t like the "for the current state" part - this exception indicates that you did something wrong, like invoke an operation on a closed stream. But in fact you did nothing wrong; the class itself is buggy.

Answer (score 0):

I would also put InvalidOperation, and explain what went wrong.

I have all kinds of internal enums that are not supposed to be used by external classes, but can be read.
so in the property set i return InvalidOperation exceptions, it makes sense, and is easy to locate.